# Remove lines where either column is empty

Tags: bash, sed, awk, text-editing

I have a large colon-delimited text file containing two columns like this:

```
valueA:valueB
valueC:
valueD:valueE
:valueG
```

If there is no data to the left *or* right of the colon, I want to remove the whole line:

```
valueA:valueB
valueD:valueE
```

How would I go about doing this?

The closest I have is something like:

```
awk -F : '$2!=""' file > final_output
```

But this seems to match everything, regardless of whether the line contains an empty column or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `awk` command properly keeps `valueA:valueB` and `valueD:valueE` example lines, and it removes the `valueC:` line (therefore I'm not sure what you mean by "seems to match *everything*").

The command keeps `:valueG` because you don't test the first field at all.

"Don't print lines where any of two columns is empty" can be coded in `awk` as:

```
awk -F : '! ( $1=="" || $2=="" )'
```

The task is equivalent to "print only lines where each column is non-empty":

```
awk -F : '$1!="" && $2!=""'
```

Note `awk` is a tool very well suited to deal with the problem. Our two lines reflect the desired logic in terms of "delimiter" (`-F :`), "columns"/"fields" (`$1`, `$2`) "being empty" (`…==""`) etc. There may be solutions with other tools, but their operation won't necessarily express the logic so clearly. E.g. with `grep`:

```
grep '.:.'
```

The above command works fine and it's simpler than the `awk` ones. Its form doesn't directly reflect the gist of the problem though. While its minimalism pleases me aesthetically, I still think `awk` is the Right Thing.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and the `grep` solution is pretty nice, though I'm a bit confused as to how it works. Isn't `.` meant to be regex for exactly one character? Why does it match more than one?

Comment: @Prometheus It doesn't match more than one. `grep` prints the *whole* line if there's a match. Compare `grep -o '.:.'`

Comment: A quick clarification - does this also remove empty lines without a `:` separator, or would I need to use another awk pattern for this?

Comment: @Prometheus Create a file with an empty line and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

With sed and three `s` commands:

```
sed 'N; s/\n:/:/; s/\n/:/; s/:$//' file
```

Output:

```
valueA:valueB:valueC
valueD:valueE:valueG
```

From `man sed`:

> `N`: Append the next line of input into the pattern space